# Need help with this simple sequence. I don't quite understand this notation

Tags: sequences-and-series

For an arbitrary but fixed , find an $_0 ()$
such that $| () | <  , ∀ ≥ _0 ()$

$ () = \frac{1}{1+}$

The solution is:

Take $_0 () =  ( \frac{1}{} ). $ For $ ≥ _0 ()$

$ x_n = \frac{1}{1+n} <= \frac{1}{1+N_0()} = \frac{1}{1+ceil(\frac{1}{})} <= \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{}} < $

From the definition it follows that $_0 ()$ is the integer number for which $\frac{1}{1+}$ is smaller than .  The solution states that $_0 () =  ( \frac{1}{} ). $ For example if we set  = 0.09, we get 11.11....ceil(11.11) = 12. Entering n in x(n) yields $\frac{1}{13}$ However $\frac{1}{12}$ is already < . So should it be the floor function instead? $_0 () = floor ( \frac{1}{} $)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find a function of $\epsilon$ that always works, regardless of $\epsilon$.

The fact that you tested one and there could be a better bound does not mean that it works for every $\epsilon$.

Try to find a counter example for your floor suggestion and see why that would break.

Comment: So to understand completely. ceil (1 / ) was choosen because 1/(1+n) always decreases faster than 1/n. n = 1 / e is  lower bound. and ceil ( 1/e) guarantees that due to rounding we are never above ?

Comment: Yes exactly. You always have to think about the worst case $\epsilon$ to make sure it will always hold.